# Exporting from Org-mode without LaTeX preamble?

Tags: emacs, preview, org-mode

Is it possible to export an *.org file to LaTeX file, **without the usual preamble** of `\documentclass[...]{article}` and a number of `\usepackage[]{xyz}`, yet take advantage of LaTeX and org-mode's math and calculation power?

I have EMACS+AUCTeX and TexLive 2013 installed on a 32-bit Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8854959) on StackOverflow help?

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't think `org-export-as-latex` is still part of org mode, with the newer `org-export-dispatch` system. However, following your link lead me in a roundabout way to a better solution, which I've posted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Edit

I was wrong, you can do this with normal org mode commands.

`C-c C-e` will invoke `org-export-dispatch`

This brings up the `Export Dispatcher` buffer. You'll notice the option for `Body Only` at the top, which is toggled with `C-b`. Set it to `On`, and then complete your export with `l l` (or whatever you like).

I'll leave my original, though now unnecessary, `pandoc` solution below.

### Original answer using pandoc

An inelegant solution using [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/index.html). From the command line, the following provides the org -> latex conversion without producing any header text:

```bash
pandoc -o file_name.tex file_name.org
```

This assumes your file is called "file_name.org". A bit of elisp to call this function from within Emacs, while you're visiting the file you wish to export:

```el
(defun my-export-to-tex ()
  "Export this buffer from org to latex."
  (interactive)
  (async-shell-command 
   (concatenate "pandoc -o "
                (file-name-base buffer-file-name)
                ".tex " buffer-file-name)))
```

Comment: Tyler, thank you for your input. I don't have time now to experiment and troubleshoot emacs so to avoid distractions I have since uninstalled both AUCTeX and emacs.